# Flatlist visible position

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to render an curved vertical list like this iOS component: https://github.com/makotokw/CocoaWZYCircularTableView

That component (written in Obj-c) iterates the visible cells when laying them out, and sets the frame (i.e. indent) using asin.

I know in React Native I can set the leftMargin style in the renderItem callback, but I can't figure out how to get the on-screen index of the item - all I have is the index into the source data.  And also, at that point, I don't think I have access to the absolute position.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is 
**onViewableItemsChanged**.
You can use it with **viewabilityConfig** which provides us with
**minimumViewTime,viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold,waitForInteraction**
which can be set accordingly

```
const VIEWABILITY_CONFIG = {
     minimumViewTime: 3000,
      viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 100,
    waitForInteraction: true,
};


 _onViewableItemsChanged = (info: {
  changed: Array<{
    key: string,
    isViewable: boolean,
    item: any,
    index: ?number,
    section?: any,
     }>
    }
 ){
  //here you can have the index which is visible to you
  }

<FlatList
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  data={this.state.data}
  onViewableItemsChanged={this._onViewableItemsChanged}
  viewabilityConfig={VIEWABILITY_CONFIG}
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for both answers.

What I have ended up doing is deriving the visible items using the scroll offset of the list.  This is simple because the list items all have the same height.

I do this in the onScroll handler, and at that point I calculate the horizontal offset for each item (and I use leftMargin / rightMargin to render this).  It's not perfect, but it does give me an elliptical list.

```
_handleScroll = (event) => {
  const topItemIndex = Math.floor(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y / LIST_ITEM_HEIGHT);
  const topItemSpare  = LIST_ITEM_HEIGHT-(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y % LIST_ITEM_HEIGHT);

  const positionFromEllipseTop = (forIndex-topItemIndex)*LIST_ITEM_HEIGHT+topItemSpare;
  const positionFromOrigin = Math.floor(Math.abs(yRadius - positionFromEllipseTop));

  const angle   = Math.asin(positionFromOrigin / yRadius);

  if (orientation === 'Left') {
    marginLeft  = 0;
    marginRight = ((xRadius * Math.cos(angle)))-LIST_ITEM_HEIGHT;
    alignSelf = 'flex-end';
  }
  else if (orientation === 'Right') {
    marginLeft  = (xRadius * Math.cos(angle))-LIST_ITEM_HEIGHT;
    marginRight = 0;
    alignSelf = 'flex-start';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

React-native's `FlatList` component has a prop called [`onLayout`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout). You can get the position of the component on screen with this prop.

> **onLayout**
>
> Invoked on mount and layout changes with:
>
> ```
> {nativeEvent: { layout: {x, y, width, height}}}
> ```
>
> This event is fired immediately once the layout has been calculated,
>   but the new layout may not yet be reflected on the screen at the time
>   the event is received, especially if a layout animation is in
>   progress.